# C++: Can not read the value inside a spesific memory address of my program using a different program

Tags: c++, memory, memory-address

I'm currently learning c++ and i decided that i want to give it a shot and try to write a simple program that can read the values of other programs that are stored in memory (and later on be able to modify these values).

To test it i wrote a program that does a simple addition, i then run my other program and I'm trying to read in real time the value of the first program using its address in the memory.

The code will help you to understand better what i mean.

The "target" program that i want to read the value from:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int userValue=0;
    int total=0;
    int* t;
    SetWindowText(NULL, "Memory");

    while(1)
    {
    cin >> userValue;
    total += userValue;
    t = &total;
    cout << *t << endl;
    cout <<"Pointer: " << &t <<" Total: " << &total;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And the program that reads the value from the first one:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DWORD address = 0x28FEF0;
    int value = 0;
    DWORD pid;
    HWND hwnd;
        hwnd = FindWindow(NULL,"Memory");
    if(!hwnd)
    {
    cout <<"Window not found!\n";
    cin.get();
    }
    else
    {
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&pid);
    HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ,0,pid);
        if(!phandle)
        {
        cout <<"Could not get handle!\n";
        cin.get();
        }
        else
        {
        while(1)
        {
        ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address,&value,sizeof(value),0);
        cout << value << "\n";

        Sleep(1000);
        }
        return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The code from the second one was taken from a forum (after googling) and it works fine if i use it with any other program, but it doesn't want to work at all with my program.

I tried changing the address to both the pointer *t* and the actual integer *total*, but nothing worked.

I feel like I've done something wrong in the first program rather than the second one.

I'm using Code:Blocks with GCC compiler.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Oh, and Merry Christmas!

Comment: There is address space layout randomization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization. Are you adjusting the address each time it changes (which should be every time you run the first program)?

Comment: Wait a minute. You did not create a window in the first program. So  you can't find one in the second..

Comment: Yes I'm adjusting the address each time it changes, that's why i have the *"cout <<"Pointer: " << &t <<" Total: " << &total;"* in the first program.

I set a title to the window, which is "Memory", I'm not sure what you mean by saying that I'm not creating one.

Comment: ***I set a title to the window, which is "Memory"*** You set the title to a window with a handle of NULL which will fail. There is no window in your first program so your second program will not find it. Your second program should have told you that since you check and return `"Window not found!\n"`

Answer (score 0):

&t = the address of the pointer that points to total

&total = the address of the actual "total value"

In your first program you should output "&total"

In your second program you should use ReadProcessMemory to read the address which is output from the first program.

If it doesn't work, you must run the second program as administrator to get permissions.  If you still have trouble, call GetLastError() after each Windows API call, check the return value of ReadProcessMemory() and utilize the last argument of ReadProcessMemory() for error checking.